# Calling remove on a FSCollection does not return the number of documents deleted

Tags: meteor, file-upload

```
Files = new FS.Collection("files");
Files.remove(); // returns undefined
```

Why remove does not return the number of files deleted like any other collection remove method ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [it does return number of deleted documents](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/blob/master/packages/collection/api.common.js#L142). You're hitting another case here.

From [`Collection.remove(selector, [callback])` documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-remove):

> As a safety measure, if `selector` is omitted (or is `undefined`), no documents will be removed. Set `selector` to `{}` if you really want to remove all documents from your collection.

Thus, to remove all documents it should be:

```
Files.remove({});
```

And it will return you the number of removed files.